# Amazon IAP Android onProductDataResponse always fails

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sku

I am trying to implement a simple subscription IAP on Android using the Amazon SDK. I adjusted their subscription sample app. The code is really simple.

```
Set <String>productSkus =  new HashSet<String>();
productSkus.add("TLS_SKU_MONTHLY" );
productSkus.add( "TLS_SKU" );
PurchasingService.getProductData(productSkus);
```

But the response from onProductDataResponse() is always fail. I'm not sure why, I cannot find any examples etc to even know if my SKUs are right, in the sample app they looked more like package names than this, but these strings are what I entered on the 'in-app items' on the apps page on Amazon. The app has not been submitted yet, but I need to test and implement IAP before that. Any ideas? I cannot even find a simple tutorial walking through this, and as usual their docs are poor.

edit, noticed im getting these errors that dont even come up on google

```
Kiwi: DataAuthenticationKeyLoaderV3: Unable to load authentication Key
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: AppstoreAuthenticationKey.pem

DATA_AUTH_KEY_LOAD_FAILURE: CERT_NOT_FOUND: null
    com.amazon.a.a.o.b.a.a: DATA_AUTH_KEY_LOAD_FAILURE: CERT_NOT_FOUND: null
```

I'm wondering, is this because I am running on real Android and not an Amazon device like a fire tablet or tv stick?

Answer (score 4):

You should add your own `AppstoreAuthenticationKey.pem` to the project assets folder. It is not (and should not be) delivered together with the sample.

Basically, you must do a few things:

0. Login to the Amazon developer console and [create your application](https://developer.amazon.com/apps-and-games/console/apps/list.html).
1. Go to the “Apk Files" tab to download `AppstoreAuthenticationKey.pem`.
2. Add this file to the project’s `assets` folder.

You can get the [full instructions from Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/integrate-appstore-sdk.html#configure_key).

As for devices, yes, you **must use an Amazon device**. But this should not be the reason why you are getting this exception.